# How to change child sample result to successful in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I've made login process with the help of jmeter. In of of request samplers I'm expecting to get response code "401". I've added *BeanShell Assertion*

```
if (ResponseCode.equals("401") == true) { 
    SampleResult.setResponseOK();  
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(true);

}
```

And my *Results Tree* is looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ9P4.png) now.

My question is - what i need to add to *BeanShell* in order to make child of the second sample green (passed) as well as it's parent sample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is using [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configured like:

[image: Response Assertion]

---

If you are still looking for Beanshell solution - you need to process all sub-results along with the main result so you should amend your code like:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

//process main sample
if (SampleResult.getResponseCode().equals("401")) {
    SampleResult.setResponseCodeOK();
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(true);
}

//process all subsamples
for (SampleResult subResult : SampleResult.getSubResults()){
    if (subResult.getResponseCode().equals("401")){
        subResult.setResponseCodeOK();
        subResult.setSuccessful(true);
    }
}
```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on using Beanshell in JMeter test scripts.

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Those who want to use not Beanshell, for groovy use `prev.setSuccessful(true)` for JS `sampleResult.setSuccessful(true)`.  http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

Comment: Actually also line `import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;` is not needed and misleading as later `SampleResult` is variable from link in my prev comment, not that import, these functions are not static.

That said, the answer helped me.